# Swift 2 Syntax Converter @objc being removed

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I am using the XCode 7 GM seed and just run the Swift syntax converter, and it seems to be doing something very strange to my @objc annotations: removing the @objc and leaving the new runtime/objc type name.

I can't find anything in the Swift 2 language reference about this new syntax, and it still refers to the @objc attribute.  What is this new declaration for?

E.g.:
`@objc(ClassName) class ClassName` becomes `(ClassName) class ClassName`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This still appears to happen in Xcode 8 beta 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting XCode and recompiling after re-adding the annotation solved the mystery, which is that "only classes inheriting from NSObject can be marked @objc."

The new non-annotation added by the Swift converter is actually illegal, and itself throws an error.